# Getting error 400 on OpenAI image edit API

Tags: javascript, openai-api

I have been testing OpenAI's [Image Edit](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/images/usage?lang=curl) API for my project and keep getting the following error in console,

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/images/edits 400
(anonymous) @ script.js:8
```

Here is my JS file code,

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('image',  'maira.png');
form.append('mask', 'maira2.png');
form.append('prompt', 'A sunlit indoor lounge area with a pool containing a flamingo');
form.append('n', '1');
form.append('size', '1024x1024');

fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/images/edits', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer *myAPIKey*'
    },
    body: form
});
```

I am expecting a JSON object in response but getting the error instead.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": null,
    "message": "Not allowed to GET on /v1/images/edits. (HINT: Perhaps you meant to use a different HTTP method?)",
    "param": null,
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
this is returned if you fetch that specific link

Comment: Error 400 is Bad Request. Try to scale down your testing - try and send only the prompt, without the mask, the image, and the rest. If that goes through, keep adding items to your `form`, until the request breaks.

Comment: @FiddlingAway When I remove the images I get the following error message 

{error: {…}}
error: 

code: null
message: "'image' is a required property"
param: null
type: "invalid_request_error"

It seems that we can't remove the images for testing.

Comment: @Delanovanlonden I am using POST method and this is what I am supposed to use as per the API doc.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have started to get "400 bad request" errors with the exact same requests that were working until a couple of days ago. I wonder if I have exceeded a quota or something (I'm doing about 3 requests per day) but in that case I'd expect a 403 error or something like that rather than a generic "bad request".